# How i can pick(select) venn diagram area

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

Is it possible to pick or select Venn diagram areas by clicking in python?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles
plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
v = venn3(subsets=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), set_labels = ('A', 'B', 'C'))
c = venn3_circles(subsets=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), linestyle='dashed')
plt.title("Sample Venn diagram")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib does support [some degree of event handling](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) as well as "pick" events for components of a plot (whether it is a Venn diagram or any other type of plot).

The Venn diagram object returned from the `venn3` function contains a field `patches`, which lists all the `PathPatch` objects which comprise the diagram. You can make those "pickable" as any other Matplotlib patch objects:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib_venn import venn3

# Create the diagram
plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
v = venn3(subsets=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), set_labels = ('A', 'B', 'C'))
plt.title("Sample Venn diagram")

# Make all patches of the diagram pickable
for p in v.patches:
    if p is not None: p.set_picker(True)

# This is the event handler
def on_pick(event):
    p = event.artist
    ec = p.get_edgecolor()
    p.set_edgecolor('black' if ec[-1] == 0.0 else 'none')
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()   # Redraw plot

# Connect event handler
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The `venn3_circles` function returns a list of three `Circle` patches, which are drawn upon the "properly segmented" diagram. You may make them pickable as well, but then you'll need to deal with "pick conflicts" somehow. Hence, in general I'd suggest you use either `venn3` (if you need 7 colored patches) or `venn3_circles` (if you only need the three circles), but not both.